# Xtext 2.8+ formatter, formatting simple rule

Tags: xtext, xtend

I am Xtend/Xtext newbie. Currently I am working with new formatter API, and i am trying to format rule, which looks like this:

```
Expression:
    Error|Warning|Enum|Text
;
```

with xtend dispatch method like this

```
def dispatch void format(Expression e){
        if (e instanceof ErrorImpl)
            ((ErrorImpl)e).format
}
```

Problem is, that type of expression e is uncovertable, I am recieving this error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<ErrorImpl> to Expression
```

Why i cannot do this conversion (*i suspect xTend semantics of course*)(*even Eclipse tells me that Expression is just interface from which children are created.*) and how can i call *format* method for every child of this rule? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of Xtend for type casts is different: instead of `(ErrorImpl) e` you write `e as ErrorImpl`. In this case the type case is not even necessary: due to the preceding `instanceof` check, the variable `e` is implicitly casted to `ErrorImpl`, so you can write the same code as

```
def dispatch void format(Expression e) {
    if (e instanceof ErrorImpl)
        e.format
}
```

However, this code would cause a stack overflow because the `format(EObject)` method is called recursively with the same input. In order to properly exploit the power of dispatch methods you should write your code like this:

```
def dispatch void format(Error error) {
    // Code for handling Errors
}
def dispatch void format(Warning warning) {
    // Code for handling Warnings
}
def dispatch void format(Enum enum) {
    // Code for handling Enums
}
def dispatch void format(Text text) {
    // Code for handling Texts
}
```

This generates a method `format(Expression)` that automatically dispatches to the more specific methods depending on the argument type.

Note that formatter dispatch methods also need a second argument of type IFormattableDocument, so they should look like

```
def dispatch void format(Error error, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
    // Code for handling Errors
}
...
```